# Getting Past IE Authentication with WebDriver

Tags: internet-explorer, python-2.7, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if anyone has used Webdriver with Python to navigate the User Authentication window which pops up in IE.

I have had it suggested to use `AutoIT`, but I would like to keep my solution strictly Python.

I have tried `python-ntlm` but keep getting stuck on an Authorization Required error when I run the script below:

```
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

user = r'userName'
password = 'password'

url = 'url goes here'

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)

# Create the NTLM Authentication Handler
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

# Create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# retrieve the result
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print response.read()
```

I am wondering how others have handled this?
Below is my webdriver script where I have tried using the `window_handles` call:

```
    def test_ie_navigation(self):
    user = 'userName'
    password = 'passWord'

    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("url I am going to")
    aw = driver.window_handles
    auth_window = driver.switch_to.window(aw[1])
    auth_window.sendKeys(user)
    auth_window.sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
    auth_window.sendKeys(password)
    auth_window.snedKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and solved it using [PyAutoIt](https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit), so my code remains pure python.

```
import autoit
autoit.win_wait_active("Windows Security")
autoit.send(user['username'])
autoit.send("{TAB}")
autoit.send(user['password'])
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

Above is my code that works on my current setup (Python 3, Internet Explorer 11, Windows 8.1 machine).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out, this should make our tests run faster since we are currently going out to a webserver to get an outside script to run. This should do it though.

Comment: I am trying to install this package, and keep getting [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 Application. I am trying to install it on a 64bit Windows 8.1 system. I have AutoIT installed and have registered both the 32 bit and the 64 bit AutoItX3 dll files. What else am I missing here?

Comment: It may help if you use virtualenv and install your python packages on a virtual environment. Installation should be easy using "pip install pyautoit" command inside your virtual environment. Also you don't need to install AutoIt, mine is working without it.

Comment: What is the advantage of using a virtualenv on a Windows machine? It's not like I am interfering with a version of python already installed on the machine like I would be with a linux or mac installation.

Comment: Using a virtualenv will isolate most of the unnecessary problems you may encounter while developing. In this case, for instance, I believe you will not encounter errors like the one you have (i.e., [Error 193] %1) if you will use virtualenv.

Comment: how did you get around selenium being stuck at driver.get('url.com')?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
def test_ie_navigation(self):
user = 'userName'
password = 'passWord'

driver = self.driver
driver.get("http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<url I am going to (Note: Don't give http/https here as it is already appended in the beginning)>") # e.g. driver.get("http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@google.co.in")
aw = driver.window_handles
auth_window = driver.switch_to.window(aw[1])
auth_window.sendKeys(user)
auth_window.sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
auth_window.sendKeys(password)
auth_window.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

See if this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response, however this does not work with IE, as it is the red-headed stepchild of browsers, it does work with Chrome and Firefox. We need to test against all three which is why I am trying to find an IE specific solution.